# Typescript Type of JSON schema object

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

Is there a special type associated with JSON-schema objects in typescript? My class has a method that checks whether its members satisfy the dynamic json schema `schema`, for now I do it like so,

```
<!-- language: typescript -->

verifySchema(schema: object): void {
    // do verification
}
```

where for example

```
<!-- language: typescript -->

const schema = {
  title: 'blabla',
  description: 'Basic schema',
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    "firstName": {
    "type": "string",
    "description": "The person's first name."
    },
    "lastName": {
    "type": "string",
    "description": "The person's last name."
    },
...
}
```

But to remain generic I would like to allow for checking arbitrary json schemas, not just this specific one. Is it okay to set `schema: object` or are there best practices for JSON-schema objects?

Comment: if you know the shape of schema, you can create an interface, otherwise, I dont see a problem

Comment: My advice is to use an already tried and tested schema validator, with TS types, instead of rolling your own.

Comment: I use a tested schema validator but I want to pass the object to be tested to it like above

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [@types/json-schema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/json-schema).

Then:

```js
import {JSONSchema7} from 'json-schema';

verifySchema(schema: JSONSchema7): void {
    // do verification
}
```

Comment: "This repository does not... implement the latest versions of JSON Schema".

Seems this repo won't be up-to-date going forward. You can see if recent changes to JSON Schema are relevant to your use case by looking at their release notes: https://json-schema.org/specification.html#migrating-from-older-drafts

Answer (score 1):

I needed to type a schema in the same way, but ideally I wanted a generic solution without an external package if possible, which allowed me to generically type the key based on a schema that can change and introduce additional property items.

I did this by adding a key index signature onto the interface meaning the key can be any `string`, but also typing additional properties for that `string` in this example this is `type` and `description` giving me the benefit of the key being generic but the keys properties are strictly typed.

```
export interface Schema {
  title: string;
  description: string;
  properties: Properties;
}

export interface Properties {
  [key: string]: {
    type: string;
    description: string;
  };
}
```

Schema can be initialised as

```
  const schema: Schema = {
    title: '',
    description: '',
    properties: {
      firstName: {
      description: '',
      type: '',
     },
     lastName: {
     description: '',
     type: '',
  },
 },
};
```

You can then access properties in the schema by its key and also benefit from intellisense suggestions, this can also be extended to support JSON `$refs` and `required` schema items.

```
const firstNameDescription = schema.properties.firstName.description;
```